# Why do we 'wear' deodorant though it is a spray?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This always makes me wonder:

### Why do we ***wear*** a deodorant?

It is just a spray i.e. mist that you put ***on*** your body.

I tried to find the verb 'wear' for this special usage in popular dictionaries but did not get the answer.

Comment: We can wear things that we draw or paint on our bodies too. What are the dictionaries or definitions given by dictionaries that make you think this usage isn't covered?

Comment: True that! I'm asking this special use of 'wear' in such cases @DamkerngT.

Comment: What could be an alternative to this? I mean, what can one do but "wear" a deodorant? In Russian, we have a special short-form participle **надушен(а)** for perfume (not sure about deodorants), but this would hardly work in English.

Comment: I have no problem with *putting on* some deo. But here...! @CopperKettle

Comment: You wear clothes after you put them on, and in the same way, you can wear deodorant after you put it on. It stays on your body just like a hat or socks.

Comment: Both Brits and Americans [usually ***use*** deodorant](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=use+deodorant%2Cwear+deodorant&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuse%20deodorant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwear%20deodorant%3B%2Cc0), rather than ***wear*** it. But when it comes to ***perfume*** (much more strongly associated with "fashionable" olfactory impact) both verbs are used about equally often.

Comment: @ColleenV that's right! It is logical as well! :) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it stands to reason that when we can use the verb wear for perfume,  we can also use it for a deodorant.

According to [MW, the entry 2 says](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wear) the verb "wear" means *to use or have something on your body* such as "Are you wearing perfume?"

Answer (score 6):

Wiktionary gives [a good list of the ways this word can be used](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wear#Verb_2).

I especially think the third definition is relevant:

> 3. To bear or display in one's aspect or appearance.
>
>    "She wore a smile all day."  "He walked out of the courtroom wearing an air of satisfaction."

"Wear" can even refer to "airs" or feelings that we give off - it's quite a flexible word!

Just for reference, at least in British English I think it's completely standard to use "wear" this way for e.g. perfume: I wear perfume, you wear perfume, are you wearing perfume? Deoderant is similar, but you might also hear "use", e.g. I'm wearing deoderant [right now], I use deoderant [when I visit my girlfriend].

Comment: Not in BrE, but in most of the registers, it's *fine*. My question is what makes only deo/tattoo a special case for the verb *wear*.

Comment: @MaulikV I'm not sure I understand you - it is not a particularly special case (as I tried to demonstrate by pointing out that you can even "wear a smile" or "wear an air of satisfaction").

Comment: @Maulik It's actually not; you can wear makeup, as jfhc mentioned you can wear a smile... I don't believe anyone "wears" a tattoo, any more than they would "wear" a birthmark, because those are permanent. To "wear" something implies impermanence.

Comment: You can [*wear* a tattoo](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/talking_point/6734849.stm). Also, I have heard it many times. @WendiKidd

Answer (score 1):

You *carry* a perfume on your skin, and that includes deodorants. In the same way that your skin *wears* any substance you may smear, rub, spray, or apply on.

Comment: But 'wear' generally 'covers' the body! I think!

Comment: You can also *put on a pair* of glasses, *put on* a sweater, and *try on* a dress. So, yes, put on some deodorant is perfectly fine, but I prefer to say: "wear a scent or perfume" because I can *feel* I'm wearing, it, and even if people  can't *see*, they can *smell* it. Women also *wear* makeup e.g. "That's a nice lipstick you're wearing".